# results.total is undefined in dojo/store/JsonRest?

Tags: dojo

I am following one of dojo/store/JsonRest tutorial (https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#dojo-store-jsonrest). As mentioned in the tutorial I am returning "Content-Range: items 0-24/66" in the header from server side (java).

I have tested in SOAP UI as well and the header is there in the server response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
**Content-Range: items 0-3/6**
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 402
Date: Thu, 16 Mar 2017 01:14:23 GMT

When I access the total as in following

```
var results = store.query({
            start: 0,
            count: 3
        }).then(function (deals){
            //do something  
        });

results.total.then(function(total){
            //do something
        });
```

Here I am getting results.total is undefined error. Any idea?

Please see screen shot is the content of results.
[Content of Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUjWf.png)

Answer (score 0):

The returned total is available as a further promise on the returned promise of data which returns the total number of available rows indicated in the Content-Range: header as a number, so you can retrieve it like this:

```
var results = store.query({
  start: 0,
  count: 3
}).then(function(deals) {
  // move this promise inside outer promise
  results.total.then(function(total) {
    //do something
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Have tried that but still getting results.total is undefined error.

Comment: @AkDev could you add to your question the content of object results from the first promise?

Comment: I added the screen shot. Hope that is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Did a few more research and found out that following code can be used to get both response data and total. Not really sure why it wasn't working on above code blocks though.

```
var results = store.query({
            start: 0,
            count: 3
        });

    results.then(function (data) {
        // You can access the response data here

        results.total.then(function (total) {
            // You can access total here

        });
    });
```